# Triple Monitor, Dual nVidia Card 18.04 Hell

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, monitor

Here's some backstory: Dual boot: Windows 10 on it's own drive (working perfectly), Ubuntu 18.04 on it's own drive.  (So, dual drive/dual boot config)  Grub 2 bootloader working as intended. 
Fresh install and config/update Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (so no previous crap to sift through).

3 monitors (40", 2x 23") 1920 x 1080 res.
Two nVidia cards: (GeForce GTX 980ti & 660ti) driver ver. 430 (prop).
980ti runs the 40" via HDMI to a reciever.  (working properly)
660ti runs the 23" via DVI.  (this is where the problem begins)

This configuration works perfectly on Win 10.  Problem only presents in Ubuntu 18.04.  Not pointing fingers as I adore this distro and want to resolve this.

Everything works - surprisingly - except any life from the 660ti (which is detected) or my 23" monitors (which are also detected, but disabled in xServer and WILL NOT display when enabled/applied).
This was not an issue with Nouveau drivers, (Ubuntu display handled extended displays and worked as intented), but screen tearing and lag was.
I have tried enabling and configuring my displays in xServer, but upon restart, I get a black screen, bootloop and my only fix is to wipe the drive and start again as recovery option does nothing.

I am reluctant to do much of anything with xServer right now without solid info regarding configuration, since I'm just happy that Ubuntu itself is booting and working.  Getting my two other monitors working would be a HUGE plus.

Thank you in advance for any help and please don't hesitate to ask more questions regarding my rig.